# Build Perl regex to match data

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

Please, help me to build a regex.

I have a lot of data with such items: '01. Item1', '02.Item3', '3D Item', 'Item next', ...

I need to build a regex, to normalize this to the following: 'Item1', 'Item3', '3D Item', 'Item next', ...;

I have tried next regex, but it cuts '3D item' to 'D item': 
`$item =~ s/^( [\d.\s]* (?=[a-zA-Z]) )? //x ;`

Comment: What does the input data look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following regex:

```
$item =~ s/^\d+\.\s*//;
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wK1zQ6)